# A Cauchy problem 2: How can I find the following solution?

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following time-dependent partial differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial V(t, x)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x\frac{\partial^2 V(t, x)}{\partial x^2}+ \theta(m-x)\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial x} - wxV(t, x), \quad t> 0, x>0\\
V(0, x ) = f(x) = e^{-ux}, \quad x>0
\end{equation}

where $\theta > 0$, $m>0$, $\sigma >0$, $u\in \mathbb{R}$, and $w\in \mathbb{R}$ are constants.

How can I come up with $\tilde{V}(t, x)$ as an initial solution for the above partial differential equation system? Could you please give me the general instruction on how I should proceed to find such a solution from the above partial differential equation?

Comment: Where in finance do these boundary conditions appear? The PDE looks like an option pricing problem, but normally you have a compact time interval with terminal payoff condition (and can use the Feynman Kac theorem)?

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes we can use Feynman Kac theorem to find a solution based on the expectation definition.

Comment: I thought the [Feynman Kac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula#Theorem) only applies if the PDE is defined over a finite time interval, $t\in[0,T]$?

Comment: No, I think so. Let me explain a little bit. Based on the Feynman Kac theorem, we already know that what the solution of the above PDE looks like. It is a conditional expectation (in order to have a martingale) that is a function of the initial value of an Ito diffusion and time. I am not interested in solving the conditional expectation as it is complicated by itself. Therefore, I want to use magic in the Feynman Kac theorem which says that if we can find an initial solution of the above PDE, then we can say that this solution is a solution for the conditional expectation as well.

Comment: I’m not sure how this would work out because I don’t think you can say “we know that a solution exists by the FK theorem” because you can’t apply the FK theorem to start with. The infinite time horizon is just the wrong setting for the FK theorem. But someone else may know how to apply some variant of the FK theorem and I’m be eager to see it!

Comment: Ok let me say it another way: We know that the conditional expectation defined in the FK theorem satisfies a Cauchy problem. Please notice that the conditional expectation has an integral from, let say, time zero up to time T. Therefore, we already consider a finite time horizon.  This time T can be any value from 0 to infinity. If we take the initial value, we will get the aforesaid boundary condition.

Comment: All in all, we can say that the classical solution $V(t, x)$ of the above Cauchy problem on $[0, T) $admits the following representation 

\begin{equation}
V(t, x) = \mathbb{E}\Big(f(X_t)\exp\{\int_{0}^{t}q(X_t) du\}|X_0 = x\Big)
\end{equation}

Now, suppose that we have the above PDE, and we can find another solution that satisfies the Cauchy problem. Then, we can say this solution is equal to the aforesaid expectation. Can you see the trick :)

Comment: As you can see, the point here is that I do not want to show the above representation is a solution to the Cauchy problem (which of course we need to say $t\in[0, T)$). I am looking for using the FK theorem the other way round.